# Getting result close to QGIS Relief algorithm using only GDAL based commands

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm trying to figure a way to output some nice vector features out of a raster DEM in order to have a pleasant visualization on a vector map. I was first trying to play with some algebraic manipulations and combinations between the DEM itself, the hillshade, aspect, slope, TPI, TRI, and many more kernel based approaches.

[image: TPI]
*TPI (Topographic Position Index)*

[image: Slope]
*Slope*

[image: Aspect]
*Aspect*

[image: Hillshade]
*Hillshade*

[image: DEM]
*Actual underlying DEM*

But I quickly noticed that the possibilities are almost infinite in the space of derived raster that you can compute from a single DEM.

Among my researches, I found this nice QGIS algorithm which I never seen before -- this may be because it is quite well hidden; it does not exist in any of the `Raster` sub-menus --, called "Relief" and which output looks like:

[image: Relief]
*QGIS Relief*
Its documentation is here at the time of writing: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasterterrainanalysis.html

I usually like to go under the hood and watch what's going on, and I was expecting a bunch of GDAL commands here, because one can see on the resulting image that at least three algorithms have been used (the computation of some contours, a TPI, and a hillshade). So I looked at the console output, but it is surprisingly quiet:

```py
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Relief' finished
QGIS version: 3.16.3-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 94ac9f21b8
Qt version: 5.9.5
GDAL version: 2.4.0
GEOS version: 3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771
PROJ version: 493
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Relief' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 
  'AUTO_COLORS' : True,
  'COLORS' : '',
  'INPUT' : '/media/data/gis/DEM.tif',
  'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
  'Z_FACTOR' : 5
}

Execution completed in 1.05 seconds
Results:
{
  'FREQUENCY_DISTRIBUTION': '',
  'OUTPUT': '/tmp/processing_1g3wgU/63301c1a5/OUTPUT.tif'
}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Relief' finished
```

I now want to tweak, experiment and configure this algorithm on a headless server where QGIS is not installed (but where GDAL is), hoping I can get some results for my desired vector features out of it.

As commented by @user2856 it seems that the QGIS Relief is based on a native QGIS algorithm: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/raster/qgsrelief.cpp

How close to the Relief result could we go using a combination of GDAL based tools only?

Other interesting links I came across:

- https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201840.pdf
- https://blog.datawrapper.de/shaded-relief-with-gdal-python/
- https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.geomorphon.html